# JSON: Converting an object into an array

Tags: java, arrays, json, type-conversion

I am the first time working with JSON and I have the requirement to receive a list of JSON elements and check the code for these elements and convert them from an object to an array. E.g.

> { 
>       "key": "my key", 
>       "value": "my value", 
>       "element": "x" 
>   }

should become:

> { 
>       "key": "my key", 
>       "value": "my value", 
>       "element": ["x"] 
>   }

The solution has to be java 1.6 compatible. 
Could anybody recommend me which parser to use in order to achieve this as simple as possible? What would the sample code look like?

Comment: That conversion from object to array isn't making much sense to me. An object contains key:value pairs, and an array contains a list of items.   One conversion is to convert key:value pairs from the object into an equivalent array of pairs, which is not entirely a well-posed conversion, but is OK for simple objects.  However, this doesn't appear to be what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you correctly but maybe this example can help you.

1) You can use jackson to work with json and for that you have to download 2 jars:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar

2) Create the next classes:

The first class is to receive you input

```
public class Input {

    private String key;
    private String value;
    private String element;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

The second class has the array of elements that you want

```
public class Output {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    private String[] element;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String[] getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(String[] element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

The third one is created to apply the conversions and run the program

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class TestJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String originalString ="{\"key\":\"my key\",\"value\":\"my value\",\"element\":\"X\"}";
        System.out.println(" Input: " + originalString);

        Input input = mapper.readValue(originalString, Input.class);
        String[] element = {input.getElement()};

        Output output = new Output();
        output.setKey(input.getKey());
        output.setValue(input.getValue());
        output.setElement(element);

        String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(output);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);

    }
}
```

After run TestJson you will see your expected result

```
 Input: {"key":"my key","value":"my value","element":"X"}
Result: {"key":"my key","value":"my value","element":["X"]}
```

Comment: Just an additional to the above, there are two main libraries which can be used to achieve this. Jackson as described above and Gson. Both have the ability to achieve the same thing and often the choice between the two is dependent on the context of what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you'll get extra credit for knowledge of both?